# Unable to scan file info using file URI in android?

Tags: android, uri, mediastore

I have Uri of file , from intent , if I open a file in my app using gallery it works well, but when I open a file in my app using file Manager , it crashes. When I try to debug while qureying over contentResolver it shows only two column available , here is the screen shot of that.
[image: Query on content resolver]

If I specify null in projection it fetches all columns as per my knowledge . Now the problem is it is not fetching all columns if i opens from file manager only in android 12 (only). I need its _ID, DATA and other info but not able to get .

here is the URI
[image]

Comment: No pictures please. You did not post code where you try to open te selected file. You also did not post the logcat/stacktrace of your crash. There is no reason that you would need a .DATA column if you got a nice content scheme.